# Magento 2 - None of transactional emails are sending

Tags: magento-2.1, transactional-mail, ssh

None of store's transactional emails are sending (order confirmation, newsletter signup confirmation, account password reset etc).

All settings in backend of magento are good (like "Disable email communication"), all store emails are set.

Cron seems to be working. Here is the rules I got:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/uspatriot/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/uspatriot/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log

*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/uspatriot/public_html/update/cron.php >> /home/uspatriot/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log

*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/uspatriot/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/uspatriot/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Here is the screenshot of DB: 
[image: Freaking pain in my behind]

I am not aware of any 3rd party modules, which would mess with emails either. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I tried to use php mail function from ssh to see if that's the problem, like this:

```
mail -s testingmail testing@gmail.com
testing message
```

Nothing happens there.

Tried to do

```
mail -v to@address.com -- -r "from@address.com"
```

It returns error that gmail thinks it's spam and therefore blocked the email.

Tried to create php file with simple php mail() function in it, and then run with

```
php filename.php
```

It returns that email has been sent, yet nothing is actually happening.

I'm pooped. HELP! :)

**UPDATE:**

There are bunch of errors like this in update.log: 
`[2017-04-21 03:31:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths: /home/uspatriot/public_html/php.ini.sample [] []` 
i don't know if that is the problem. Tried to google - not much info on it.

**UPDATE 2:**

Got this from server support folks:

*It appears the PHP Mail function is enabled and working properly on the server at this time. I did a quick check for the function to insure it was enabled and then sent a test message manually via command line to my gmail account. I received this within the exim_maillog after that test:
This log shows the sending of the message through the PHP Mailer to my test gmail account:

```
2017-04-20 23:08:18 cwd=/root 4 args: send-mail -i -- lwtestingbodonald@gmail.com
2017-04-20 23:08:18 1d1Ovi-000NzU-4X <= root@liquid.regexseo.com U=root P=local S=556 T="Iron Maiden" for lwtestingbodonald@gmail.com
2017-04-20 23:08:18 1d1Ovi-000NzU-4X ** lwtestingbodonald@gmail.com R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.126.27] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes:
```

However gmail did deny the message at their SMTP server due to the message being sent from root and gmail believes it to be a spam message.
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:

```
550-5.7.1 [67.225.162.240] The IP address sending this message does not have a\n550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from\n550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit\n550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more\n550 5.7.1 information. l130si775055ita.29 - gsmtp
```

In conclusion to the original inquiry, all of this indicates that the PHP Mail function is active and working on the server. If you could give us some steps in order to replicate the issue you are encountering we will be able to better investigate. *

Comment: Do you have an MTA like Postfix on your server or are you just relying upon the send mail Linux script to "just work"?  Are you using a host that has disabled the sending of emails from their servers (like Amazon Web Services)?  If the send mail program is not returning an error, then PHP will take that as the mail being sent.  Is there anything in you /var/log/syslog relating to send mail or the emails?

Comment: Server uses EXIM. I'm hosting with Liquid Web, I got VPS there and other accounts can send emails no problem. The only Email related thing in the log is exception of trying to create user with the existing email. So, no, no exceptions or errors.

Comment: There are bunch of errors like this in update.log: `[2017-04-21 03:31:02] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:  /home/uspatriot/public_html/php.ini.sample [] []` i don't know if that is the problem. Tried to google - not much info on it.

Comment: Did you also set up PTR records on your domain to indicate that your VPS is allowed to send mail for that domain?

Comment: Yes, PTR is set up, at least according to server support:
`Yes, you do have a PTR record, which is your reverse DNS. You can see that here:
dig uspatriotarmory.com +short
67.225.162.240

dig -x 67.225.162.240 +short
liquid.regexseo.com.`

Answer (score 0):

From the logs you posted and the conclusion that Gmail is discarding the emails sent because it's coming from an unreal email address.  The easiest solution is to set up a "dummy" email address on your domain and then proxy your exim to send through your domain's email provider.  I know Postfix can achieve this very easily, not sure about Exim.

Answer (score 0):

Many people struggle with this problem and try many solutions only to come to find out that the problem is that shell access is disabled in your account. If shell access is disabled in your account (especially for shared hosting servers), confirm your cron command url to the cron.php file is correct in cPanel and then modify your cron.php just below line 49: Add this line: $isShellDisabled = true;
This works and I tested on Magento 1.9 running on a shell disabled hosting.